# Span a table cell to five rows

Tags: html

I have created a html table as it is seen in the picture below, now I want the packing list cell to span five rows down. I have tried several ways but have not succeeded. Looks simple but its killing me, help guys!

[Image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tICe.png) of the Table

```html
    <TABLE border=1 style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 43%">
        <col style="width: 11%">
        <col style="width: 24%">
        <col style="width: 35%">
    
    </colgroup>
    <THEAD>
    <TR>
        <TH rowspan="5"><b>ISSUER</b></TD>
        <TH style="text-align:center" colspan="3" rowspan="5">PACKING LIST</TD>
    
    </TR>
    </THEAD>
    <TR>
        <td>
            <p>Jonathan Vehicle Assemblers Limited</p>
            <p>Plot 673 TA Industrial Park</p>
            <p>Kibaha, Tanzania</p>
        </td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <td><b>TO:</b></td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <td>
            <p>Jifag Motors (T) Limited</p>
            <p>Nyerere Road</p>
            <p>P.O Box 40935402</p>
        </td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <td><b>LOCATION:</b></td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <td rowspan="3">Assembly at Kibaha, Tanzania</td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>PACKING LIST NO.:</b></td>
        <td colspan="1"><b>DATE</b></td>
    <TR>
        <td colspan="2">GFA-PL-2020-00001</td>
        <td>06-Nov-20</td>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: can you share a image which u want. to make....?

Comment: check the image link above or run the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 43%">
        <col style="width: 11%">
        <col style="width: 24%">
        <col style="width: 35%">    
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="5"><b>ISSUER</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:center" colspan="3" rowspan="5">PACKING LIST</th>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Jonathan Vehicle Assemblers Limited</p>
            <p>Plot 673 TA Industrial Park</p>
            <p>Kibaha, Tanzania</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="4" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>TO:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Jifag Motors (T) Limited</p>
            <p>Nyerere Road</p>
            <p>P.O Box 40935402</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>LOCATION:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Assembly at Kibaha, Tanzania</td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>PACKING LIST NO.:</b></td>
        <td colspan="1"><b>DATE</b></td>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">GFA-PL-2020-00001</td>
        <td>06-Nov-20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot one more thing, also I want to kill the empty cell and the packing list cell should span down to take the empty space

Comment: Not possible to span down the **packing list ** cell, as it is the column heading of the table.

Comment: what if I change from <th> to <td>, though I have tried but didn't see the result. In general my aim is to make packing list cell and empty cell be one cell